# How to add some text labels to roundSlider

Tags: javascript, html, round-slider

Below, is the html script that I have for the roundSlider widget, I was trying to add some label text into this widget but couldn't figure it out. Since I will need multiple widgets of those for my project, I will have to give each one a different label/name.

In the below attached image, thats where I am thinking of adding these labels

Please, any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

html script:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>roundSlider</title>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>
    
    .slider {
     position: absolute;
     align:center;
    }    
    
    .row1 {top:100px;}
    
    
    .col1 {left:75px;}
    
    
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <div id="slider1" class='slider row1 col1'></div>
    <!--  <p>Slider</p> -->
    
    
    
    
    <script>
    
      // create sliders
    
      $("#slider1").roundSlider({
        sliderType: "min-range",
        radius: 150,
        min: 0,
    
        max: 100,
        value: 0, // default value at start
        //change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide1_val: event.value}); }
        change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/set_my_number/' + event.value); }
      });
    
    
    
      $("#turn_off_button").click(function(){
          // set sliders
          $("#slider1").data("roundSlider").setValue(0);
    
    
          // send to server
          $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
            slide1_val: 0,
    
          });
      });
    
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Image:

[roundSlider Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqot0.png)

Three roundSlides:

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>roundSlider</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>

<style>

.slider {
 position: absolute;
 align:center;
}    

.row1 {top:100px;}
.row2 {top:450px;}
.row3 {top:750px;}


.col1 {left:75px;}
.col2 {left:470px;}
.col3 {left:870px;}


</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="slider1" class='slider row1 col1'></div>


<div id="slider2" class='slider row1 col2'></div>


<div id="slider3" class='slider row1 col3'></div>



<script>

  // create sliders

  $("#slider1").roundSlider({
    sliderType: "min-range",
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,

    max: 100,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    //change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide1_val: event.value}); }
    change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/set_my_number/' + event.value); }
  });


  $("#slider2").roundSlider({
    sliderType: "min-range",
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    value: 0, // default value at start

    //change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide2_val: event.value}); }
    change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/set_abcd/' + event.value); }
  });

  $("#slider3").roundSlider({
    sliderType: "min-range",
    radius: 150,
    min: 0,
    max: 10000000000,
    value: 0, // default value at start
    //change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide3_val: event.value}); }
    change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/set_fghkva/' + event.value); }
  });

  $("#turn_off_button").click(function(){
      // set sliders
      $("#slider1").data("roundSlider").setValue(0);


      // send to server
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide1_val: 0,

      });
  });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to insert text at the position where zero is at  ?

Comment: @XxSTREKxX, I am not sure if I understand your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the position absolute so that your text appears after the slider.
Hope this is what you expected.

If you are using multiple sliders use flex to add numerous sliders with one parent div for both the slider and paragraph

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>roundSlider</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
  }
  .child
  {
  margin-left:100px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child">
      <div id="slider1" class='slider row1 col1'></div>

      <center>
        <p>slider1</p>
      </center>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <div id="slider2" class='slider row1 col2'></div>
      <center>
        <p>slider1</p>
      </center>
    </div>

    <div class="child">
      <div id="slider3" class='slider row1 col3'></div>

      <center>
        <p>slider1</p>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    // create sliders

    $("#slider1").roundSlider({
      sliderType: "min-range",
      radius: 150,
      min: 0,

      max: 100,
      value: 0, // default value at start
      //change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide1_val: event.value}); }
      change: function(event) {
        $.getJSON('/set_my_number/' + event.value);
      }
    });


    $("#slider2").roundSlider({
      sliderType: "min-range",
      radius: 150,
      min: 0,
      max: 1000,
      value: 0, // default value at start

      //change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide2_val: event.value}); }
      change: function(event) {
        $.getJSON('/set_abcd/' + event.value);
      }
    });

    $("#slider3").roundSlider({
      sliderType: "min-range",
      radius: 150,
      min: 0,
      max: 10000000000,
      value: 0, // default value at start
      //change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide3_val: event.value}); }
      change: function(event) {
        $.getJSON('/set_fghkva/' + event.value);
      }
    });

    $("#turn_off_button").click(function() {
      // set sliders
      $("#slider1").data("roundSlider").setValue(0);


      // send to server
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide1_val: 0,

      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code is good for one roundSlider, what if I have multiple sliders as I mentioned in my question above? I added another 3 sliders script, check it please.

Comment: @muneers i just updated the answer too it will work for any number of sliders

Comment: OUTSTANDING! Thanks a LOT.

Comment: Kindly, one more little thing and will be done with it, I just wonder how to make a space between each other. They just look like stuck to each other, I want to separate them from each other a little bit.

Comment: @muneers added left margin to the child elements

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: @muneers never mention

Comment: would you please take a look at my new thread about sliders: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57792647/how-to-add-a-enable-disable-button-to-the-roundslider-widget

Answer (score 1):

In roundSlider you have the **`tooltipFormat`** property, through which you can make any custom tooltip text or element.

Refer the below demos:

https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/deLqk8sr/

https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/deLqk8sr/1

https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/deLqk8sr/131/

https://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#custom-tooltip

#### Some use-case demos:

https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/j7ady5o8/

https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/jwjwrLw7/

Hopes this helps you...

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input.

Comment: would you please take a look at my new thread about sliders: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57792647/how-to-add-a-enable-disable-button-to-the-roundslider-widget

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below inside the call to roundSlider after the change event

```
create: function(event) {$(".rs-tooltip-text").append("<br/><span>test</span>");}
```

just uses the class for the existing tooltip and appends some html after that

Comment: would you please apply your solution to my three sliders example above, I tried it but didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: $("#slider1").roundSlider({
        sliderType: "min-range",
        radius: 150,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 0, // default value at start
        //change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide1_val: event.value}); }
        change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/set_my_number/' + event.value); },
        create: function(event) {$(".rs-tooltip-text").append("<br/><span>test</span>");}
    });

Comment: that was cool, but the problem is when I drag the slider the text disappears!

Comment: Just apply the same to onchange event as well like below

Comment: change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/set_my_number/' + event.value); $(".rs-tooltip-text").append("<br/><span>test</span>");},
        create: function(event) {$(".rs-tooltip-text").append("<br/><span>test</span>");}