# How to add a enable/disable button to the roundSlider widget?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, round-slider

In the below snippet code I have a three roundSlider widgets, and I am trying to add a enable/disable button under each slider.

Please, I would highly appreciate your help to show/guide me how to add a these enable/disable button to whether aside of the widgets or preferably a button under each slider.

code:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>roundSlider</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/roundSlider/1.3.2/roundslider.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
  }
  .child
  {
  margin-left:100px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child">
      <div id="slider1" class='slider row1 col1'></div>

      <center>
        <p>slider1</p>
      </center>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <div id="slider2" class='slider row1 col2'></div>
      <center>
        <p>slider2</p>
      </center>
    </div>

    <div class="child">
      <div id="slider3" class='slider row1 col3'></div>

      <center>
        <p>slider3</p>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    // create sliders

    $("#slider1").roundSlider({
      sliderType: "min-range",
      radius: 150,
      min: 0,

      max: 100,
      value: 0, // default value at start
      //change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide1_val: event.value}); }
      change: function(event) {
        $.getJSON('/set_my_number/' + event.value);
      }
    });


    $("#slider2").roundSlider({
      sliderType: "min-range",
      radius: 150,
      min: 0,
      max: 1000,
      value: 0, // default value at start

      //change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide2_val: event.value}); }
      change: function(event) {
        $.getJSON('/set_abcd/' + event.value);
      }
    });

    $("#slider3").roundSlider({
      sliderType: "min-range",
      radius: 150,
      min: 0,
      max: 10000000000,
      value: 0, // default value at start
      //change: function(event) { $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {slide3_val: event.value}); }
      change: function(event) {
        $.getJSON('/set_fghkva/' + event.value);
      }
    });

    $("#turn_off_button").click(function() {
      // set sliders
      $("#slider1").data("roundSlider").setValue(0);


      // send to server
      $.getJSON('/valueofslider', {
        slide1_val: 0,

      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831601/disabling-and-enabling-a-html-input-button) to see how you disable / enable buttons via javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [roundSlider](https://roundsliderui.com/document.html#options) having the enable and disable methods, so you can maintain any state and based on the state you can toggle the state of the slider.

In the below demo I have achieved that functionality and based on your application scenario you can reuse this:

## [`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/x10rbfqp/103/)

Comment: OUTSTANDING! Thanks a LOT.

Comment: just out of curiosity, do you think I can set these sliders to disabled state by default once I run the program, then I can later enable whatever slider I need? I tried to add 'state: disabled,' to the sliders parameters but this line made sliders disappear!

Comment: I found it. It should be=>  disabled: true  instead of    state: disabled

Comment: would you please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811127/how-to-enable-disable-a-function-in-python-flask

Comment: sorry, I am not aware of python.